# fail function called even after ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax

fail function is being called even after the ajax post has been made followed by always function being called but done function is not called. Why it's happening ?

```
$('#askques').submit(function(event) {  
            event.preventDefault();               
            $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'post.php',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        dataType: 'json',
                       })
                       .done(function(data) { alert( data );})
                       .fail(function() {alert( "error" ) ;})
                       .always(function(data) 
                       {alert(data);
                        $(".sub").attr("disabled","1"); 
                      });
                    });
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php

//error_reporting(0);

//$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$fname = $_POST["fname"]; //$data->name;
$lname = $_POST["lname"];//$data->fname;
$ques = $_POST["ques"];//$data->ques;
$ans = $_POST["ans"];//$data->ans;

$myfile = fopen("data.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = $fname." ".$lfname." ".$ques." ".$ans;

fwrite($myfile, $txt);

fclose($myfile);

//$data = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
//echo json_encode($data);

echo "Done";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `dataType: 'json',` designates that the return type from server must be a valid JSON, yet your server is not sending JSON back. Either remove the `dataType` from request, or encode your response as JSON